# Compiling a single file without an IDE, c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, compilation

I´m working on a unit tester for c++, mostly for practice, but I´m stuck.

The way I want it to work is as follows:

1. It reads all class and function names from all .hpp files within a defined test folder and its sub-folders. These have assertions that are linked to a logger that outputs HTML files with the test results.
2. It creates a single .hpp or .cpp file that creates one instance of every test class and runs every function in it.
3. It compiles the .hpp/.cpp file created in step 2.
4. It runs the output of step 3.

I have 1. and 2. down but I´m having trouble compiling the .hpp file I created. I initially wanted to compile using a simple call to cl.exe but that is proving to be more problematic than I originally anticipated.

Do any of you know of a good/simple way of compiling a single file?
I have done some research on make/nmake but I can´t figure out how to accomplish this with them.

Also, if this method of doing unit tests is completely stupid, please let me know.

Some info:
    I´m using Windows 7 64-bit and Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You need to tell us what problems you are facing - `that is proving to be more problematic than I originally anticipated.` is just not enough info.

Comment: Hmm, I need to think this out a bit more. I realize my question is rather vague. Thanks for the comment. -Freddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the generated `something.cpp` file contains `#include "something.hpp"`, then it should just be a case of `cl something.cpp` and you get a `something.exe`, which you can run in some suitable way.

"Calling every funciton on an object" seems a little strange - how do you know whether the result is correct? If we have a complex object, it may require more than creation to support calling all functions. What parameters are you passing in to each function? How do you know what it should return?

Comment: Since I´m just doing this for practice, I assume that all the functions are void and take no parameters.
The main goal of this exercise was to get familiar with windows filesystems(creating directories, generating files, calling a compiler, etc.) and specifically to learn how to use the boost::filesystem.
I only generated a single header file, it #included all the .hpp files(from the test classes). It was basically just supposed to be a main file, which is why I originally made a file called RunTests.cpp.

Thanks for the quick reply.

-Freddie